# Why object's value type doesn't infer when key returned from function?

Tags: typescript

Does it an expected behaviour or not? When I'm passing string to object TypeScript infer its value type, but when key passed as function return value - it doesn't.

```
function getB(): 'b' {
    return 'b';
}

type A = {
    b: (arg: string) => void;
};

// Parameter 'arg' implicitly has an 'any' type.

const a = {
    [getB()]: (arg) => {
        console.log(arg);
    },
} as A;

// This is OK

const b = {
    ['b']: (arg) => {
        console.log(arg);
    },
} as A;

// This is also OK

const key = getB();

const c = {
    [key]: (arg) => {
        console.log(arg);
    },
} as A;
```

I'm expecting that value type will infer when key come from function